# Introspect and iterate over static/computed properties in an enum

Tags: swift, enums, introspection, swift-protocols

The `CaseIterable` protocol lets you iterate through the cases of an enum, I want to do that but for static properties, and also get its values. How would you implement the theoretical `PropertyIterable` protocol?

I've tried using reflection (`Mirror(reflecting:)`), it works on structs but not on enums

For example:

```
protocol PropertyIterable {
  var allProperties: [String: T] { get }  //will get you [String: Any/T]
}
```

*FYI*: Maybe computed property `allProprties` is not defined properly. But is just for illustration purposes

```
enum Test: PropertyIterable {
  static let foo = "blah"
  static let bar = "blah2"
}


let test = Test.allProperties //will return ["foo": "blah", bar: "blah2"]
```

Currently, when I print `Mirror(describing: Test.self).children` I get this:

```
AnyCollection<(label: Optional<String>, value: Any)>(_box: Swift._RandomAccessCollectionBox<Swift.LazyMapCollection<Swift.Range<Swift.Int>, (label: Swift.Optional<Swift.String>, value: Any)>>)
```

Comment: That type you're seeing is a lazy type that wraps the values of `Test`. Since most people will only want to iterate the values, there's no point in copying them into a fresh Array. You can do that yourself, if that's what you need, with `Array(Mirror(describing: Test.self).children)`. But then, you'll discover that mirror doesn't work on these custom properties :(

Comment: @Alexander I tried `Array(Mirror(describing: Test.self).children)` and I got an empty array. So, there is no way to get the values of all defined properties in an enum? I want to use enums to store and organize constants. I got the idea from Natasha, the robot:
https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-enum-no-cases/

Comment: Nope, there's no automated way. At best, you could make a computed property that returns a dict of values, that have been manually listed.

Comment: Do you know if there's a proposal to to implement something like that? Or why would be worth to get the cases as with `CaseIterable` but not the properties?

Comment: The compiler already bakes in this meta data into the executables it builds. The debugger tools take advantage of this metadata, but there's no API (besides Mirror, which is almost useless) for accessing it. They haven't implemented that because it's still undergoing quite a lot of change. That hasn't stopped third parties from reverse engineering it and implementing reflection libraries, though. Just beware that they're going to be prone to breaking as these implementation details change in future Swift versions.

Answer (score -1):

If we use `CaseIterable`, we should be able to use `allCases.reduce` to reduce it from a `[Test]` into a `[Test:String]`

Remember to conform your enum to `String` so as to access `rawValue`.

```swift
protocol PropertyIterable: Hashable, CaseIterable {
    var rawValue: String { get }
    static var allProperties: [Self: String] { get }
}
extension PropertyIterable {
    static var allProperties: [Self: String] {
        allCases.reduce([Self:String]()) {
            var newValue = $0
            newValue[$1] = $1.rawValue
            return newValue
        }
    }
}

enum Test: String, PropertyIterable {
    case foo = "blah"
    case bar = "blah2"
}

let test = Test.allProperties
print(test) // prints: [Test.bar: "blah2", Test.foo: "blah"]
```

Comment: This is not what the author is asking for. They want to loop over static properties, not the cases.